# cannot select option when multiple radio buttons are used

Tags: html, css

I have used two radio buttons to select the gender of applicant and gender of applicant's child.But both of them does not works.Can anyone help me with this?
My codes are given below

```css
         input[type=radio] {
         position: absolute;
         visibility: hidden;
         display: none;
        }
       label {
         color: #9a929e;
         display: inline-block;
         cursor: pointer;
          font-weight: bold;
         padding: 5px 20px;
       }
        input[type=radio]:checked + label {
        color: #ccc8ce;
        background: #675f6b;
        }
```

```html
        <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="selector" checked>
        <label for="option-one">One</label>  
        <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="selector">
        <label for="option-two">Two</label>
        
        <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="selector_one" checked>
        <label for="option-one">One</label>  
        <input type="radio" id="option-two" name="selector_one">
        <label for="option-two">Two</label>
```

Comment: works fine in the snippet. What do you mean with "do not work"?

Comment: Yes, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Try clicking the second "Two"

Comment: @j08691 when I posted the comment there was only one radio with yes/no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "id" can be used only once in an html page. Each "id" must be unique.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
 }

label {
  color: #9a929e;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #ccc8ce;
  background: #675f6b;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="option-one" name="selector" checked>
<label for="option-one">One</label>  
<input type="radio" id="option-two" name="selector">
<label for="option-two">Two</label>

<input type="radio" id="option-one2" name="selector_one" checked>
<label for="option-one2">One</label>  
<input type="radio" id="option-two2" name="selector_one">
<label for="option-two2">Two</label>
```